# Import Magento 2 Database On Live Server

Tags: magento2

Magento 2 database is working properly on local but I got FULLTEXT issue in importing magento 2 database on live server.Please provide the solution.

Comment: add some more details of error that you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

Not very much information to work with, but FULLTEXT Index issue is usually related to MySQL engine. Make sure your Database works with InnoDB or MyISAM. 
You can use `SHOW TABLE STATUS` to find out. If it shows anything other than InnoDB or MyISAM then that is your problem.